# JQuery - Manipulation of new element without event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tree plugin which creates many new DOM elements. After tree is created, I need to adjust some parameters during the time page is loading, before user can start interacting with the page. I dont have any problems with new DOM element's manipulation after click though - `.click` was not enought, but `on.('click' , function(){//do sth})` does it job. It tried something similar like on live, on load but it just doesnt work. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //create tree
    $('#tree1').tree();

    //manipulate some new element created by tree() automatically - doesnt work
    $('.some-element').attr('someattr', 'value');

    //manipulate some new element created by tree() after event - does work
    $(document).on('click', '.some-element', function(){
        $(this).attr('someattr', 'value');
    });

});
```

Comment: You need to read the documentation for the tree plugin, and see if it's somehow async, and if so if it has a callback for when the elements have been created-

Comment: so there is no standard way of doing that? or it cannot be done in case sth is async only? If it cannot be done only in that case, I will read the documentation, but what if there was no async method? How could I achieve what I need then?

Comment: If the call to `tree()` is synchronous, the elements would be there when you're trying to access them on the next line with `$('.some-element')`, if the elements are there yet, it's async.

Comment: jQuery cannot manipulate elements that are not on the page when you try to select them. The only way for this to work is to wait until `tree()` has finished adding these elements.

Comment: and I can find out about this by callback function correct? If yes I understand everything and thx for your help

Comment: Woohoo, could you please give me an example, would I need to provide fixed time and then check it or it would just wait until element is ready, after which I could manipulate this element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments above say, you'll have to look at the documentation to see what is being inserted, but an example of how to grab the elements as they are inserted is:

(in this case it is an element being inserted with the class `some-element` into the element with the id `tree1`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //create tree
    $('#tree1').tree();

    // wait for the element to be inserted...
    $('#tree1').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.some-element', function () {
        $(this).attr('someattr', 'value');
    });

    //manipulate some new element created by tree() after event - does work
    $(document).on('click', '.some-element', function(){
        $(this).attr('someattr', 'value');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I read the documentation and what I tried to achieve was impossible as this tree plugin inserts new elements even after clicking on elements multiple times. I will need to either get some help from server side during tree creation, or create some objects with necessary info and use it in callback functions and/or  try almightyBoognish solution.

Btw how to accept answers in comments below my initial question? I can accept only almightyBoognish's reply and I would like to thank you all:)